Why am I getting inconsistent results from the Ivy deliver task?
I'm using Ivy's resolve, deliver, and makepom tasks as part of an Ant target that publishes artifacts to a maven repository.  The output of the resolve task shows a number of modules evicted in favor of newer revisions, and when I run the build locally, the output of makepom reflects those newer revisions, and that's the desired result.  When I run the same build (with the same versions of Ant/Ivy) in a Docker container as part of a Bitbucket pipeline, the output of resolve still shows the same evictions, but the output of makepom reflects the older, evicted revisions instead of the newer ones.
Example:
The Ant target looks like this:
<target name="publishprep" depends="thejar,srcjar">
   <!-- if the forcedrev property is set, use its value as the build revision; otherwise use the distversion property -->
   <condition property="buildrev" value="${forcedrev}" else="${distversion}">
      <isset property="forcedrev"/>
   </condition>

   <!-- revolve for the specified build revision -->
   <ivy:resolve revision="${buildrev}"/>

   <!-- generate a resolved ivy.xml file -->
   <ivy:deliver deliverpattern="${distdir}/[artifact].[ext]"/>

   <!-- convert the ivy.xml to a Maven pom -->
   <ivy:makepom ivyfile="${distdir}/ivy.xml" pomfile="${distdir}/${artifactname}.pom">
      <ivy:mapping conf="dev" scope="provided"/>
      <ivy:mapping conf="*" scope="compile"/>
   </ivy:makepom>
</target>

ivy.xml includes these dependencies:
<dependency org="com.itextpdf" name="layout" rev="7.2.4"/>
<dependency org="myorg" name="mc-dtdcore" rev="1.2.15"/>

The POM for the mc-dtdcore artifact includes this:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
  <version>7.2.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

When I build locally, the resolve tasks decides to evict revision 7.2.4 in favor of 7.2.5 due to the transitive dependency, and the ivy.xml file produced by the subsequent deliver task includes this dependency:
<dependency org="com.itextpdf" name="layout" rev="7.2.5" revConstraint="7.2.4"/>

which the makepom task turns into this (as expected):
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
  <version>7.2.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

When the same build runs in the context of a Bitbucket pipeline, the resolve task still indicates that it's evicting 7.2.4 in favor of 7.2.5. But the deliver task seems to ignore that, and produces an ivy.xml file with this dependency:
<dependency org="com.itextpdf" name="layout" rev="7.2.4"/>

which makepom turns into a POM that references 7.2.4.
I've attempted to get some insight by running the build with Ant's -verbose flag, but even then the deliver task doesn't log much of anything, and the resolve task appears to be doing the same thing in both cases.  I've checked the build status, but it's always integration, regardless of how/where I'm running the build.  I've confirmed that both environments are using the same version of Ivy (2.5.2) and pointing at the same repository.  I'm unclear on why revConstraint is populated the way it is in the local builds (there are no dynamic revision specifications in play here at all), but I'm really unclear on why it isn't populated at all in the pipeline builds.
